# Hazelcast near-cache eviction doesn't work

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast 3.7.4, and I have both lite and non-lite members.

On my lite members I'm setting near-cache as follows:

```
        NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig(0, cacheSize, EvictionPolicy.LRU.name(), 0, true, InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
        config.getMapConfig(mapName).setNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);
```

I have configured entry listener on my lite member and could verify that it is called on change. Moreover, the old and new value content is correct.

But when I'm trying to get the value from the map I'm still getting the old value.

While debugging, I've tried to look at the map content and I could see the new value, but when I'm calling: `map.get(key)` the old value is returned.

Comment: `IMap` and its near cache have isolated eviction mechanisms. When an entry is evicted from `IMap`, this doesn't require an eviction on near cache or vice versa. So it can be expected that near cache returns the evicted entry because it still owns it. Since eviction doesn't affect correctness of the data, if the latest state is still observable, returning it from near cache should not cause any problem even `IMap` doesn't have it.

Comment: Let's say that the key 'a' was mapped to the value '1', but then changed to '2', how could it make sense that I'll still get '1' when I'm querying the map for 'a'? 

I'm not talking about eviction here but value update.
Moreover, one of the near-cache constructor is ``invalidateOnChange``, which is set to ``true`` in my code.

Comment: could you share full example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's apparently a bug, the answer I got from HZ team:

> Thanks for reporting this, indeed it is a bug for 3.7 version. 3.8-EA don't have this issue.
>   Root cause of the issue is invalidations are not sent to lite-members if near cache is not configured also on other members.
>
> For now, as a workaround you can enable near cache on other members.
>   Possibly we can fix this issue in next 3.7 patch release which will be
>   3.7.6.

As a workaround, as suggested, I've enabled near cache on the other members (only for this map) and it solved the problem.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/9723