# Hazelcast Near Cache: Evict if changed on different node

Tags: caching, hazelcast, spring-cache, hazelcast-imap

I am using Spring + Hazelcast 3.8.2 and have configured a map like this using the Spring configuration:

```xml
<hz:map name="test.*" backup-count="1"
    max-size="0" eviction-percentage="30" read-backup-data="true"
    time-to-live-seconds="900"
    eviction-policy="NONE" merge-policy="com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy">
    <hz:near-cache max-idle-seconds="300"
        time-to-live-seconds="0"
        max-size="0" />
</hz:map>
```

I've got two clients connected (both on same machine [test env], using different ports).

When I change a value in the map on one client the other client still has the old value until it will get evicted from the near cache due to the expired idle time.

I found a similar issue like this here: [Hazelcast near-cache eviction doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789904/hazelcast-near-cache-eviction-doesnt-work)

But I'm unsure if this is really the same issue, at least it is mentioned that this was a bug in version 3.7 and we are using 3.8.2.

Is this a correct behaviour or am I doing something wrong? I know that there is a property `invalidate-on-change`, but as a default this is `true`, so I don't expect I have to set this one.

I also tried setting the `read-backup-data` to `false`, doesn't help.

Thanks for your support

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

The issue is that Hazelcast sends the invalidations by default in batches and thus it waits a few seconds until the invalidations will be sent out to all other nodes.

You can find more information about this here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache-invalidation

So I had to set the property `hazelcast.map.invalidation.batch.enabled` to `false` which will immediately send out invalidations to all nodes. But as mentioned in the documentation this should only be used when there aren't too many put/remove/... operations expected, as this will then make the event system very busy.

Nevertheless, even though this property is set it will not guarantee that all nodes will directly invalidate the near cache entries. I noticed that after directly accessing the values on the different node sometimes it's fine, sometimes not.

Here is the JUnit test I built up for this:

```java
@Test
public void testWithInvalidationBatchEnabled() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.map.invalidation.batch.enabled", "true");

    doTest();
}

@Test
public void testWithoutInvalidationBatchEnabled() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.map.invalidation.batch.enabled", "false");

    doTest();
}

@After
public void shutdownNodes() {
    Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
}

protected void doTest() throws Exception {
    // first config for normal cluster member
    Config c1 = new Config();
    c1.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5709);

    // second config for super client
    Config c2 = new Config();
    c2.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5710);

    // map config is the same for both nodes
    MapConfig testMapCfg = new MapConfig("test");
    NearCacheConfig ncc = new NearCacheConfig();
    ncc.setTimeToLiveSeconds(10);
    testMapCfg.setNearCacheConfig(ncc);

    c1.addMapConfig(testMapCfg);
    c2.addMapConfig(testMapCfg);

    // start instances
    HazelcastInstance h1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(c1);
    HazelcastInstance h2 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(c2);

    IMap<Object, Object> mapH1 = h1.getMap("test");
    IMap<Object, Object> mapH2 = h2.getMap("test");

    // initial filling
    mapH1.put("a", -1);

    assertEquals(mapH1.get("a"), -1);
    assertEquals(mapH2.get("a"), -1);

    int updatedH1 = 0, updatedH2 = 0, runs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mapH1.put("a", i);

        // without this short sleep sometimes the nearcache is updated in time, sometimes not
        Thread.sleep(100);

        runs++;
        if (mapH1.get("a").equals(i)) {
            updatedH1++;
        }
        if (mapH2.get("a").equals(i)) {
            updatedH2++;
        }
    }

    assertEquals(runs, updatedH1);
    assertEquals(runs, updatedH2);
}
```

`testWithInvalidationBatchEnabled` finishs only sometimes successfully, `testWithoutInvalidationBatchEnabled` finishs always successfully.